# XCode 4.4 "Permission denied" when trying to download Application Data

Tags: iphone, xcode4.4

After updating my XCode to version 4.4 it seems to be impossible to retrieve Application Data from my devices.

In Xcode 4.3 (and all previuos version) I downloaded my Application Data (like SQLite databases and files I created) through the organizer (Organizer -> Devices -> "Device" -> Applications -> "Application" -> Download).

With Xcode 4.4 i get an error ("Permission Denied") when I try to download the Documents from the sandbox.

Is there anything new (maybe a new setting?) I have to change to obtain the Application Data from my device again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporary fix is using itunes to get the files from the document folder.

In your .plist -> Information property list -> add:

`UIFileSharingEnabled` (YES)

Rebuild and go to itunes and get the files from document folder.

Comment: Makes it a bit more complicated to receive the files, but this works, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to restore the data using iTunes? I tried but my Application data is in sub-folder and using "Add" does not put the folder contents inside the sub-folder - just in the root directory.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem and will give a little more information:

Even though Xcode gives the "Permission Denied" error, it does export two files into a xcappdata file and does not even export the "Documents" folder.

```
AppDataInfo.plist
com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist
```

Then I deleted the app and all data off the device and reinstalled it using Xcode. I exported the data after running the app and generating a log (log saved into the documents folder). This new log file was properly exported inside the "Documents" folder, but Xcode still generated the "Permission Denied" error.

After further running the app and generating logs, attempting to export the new data resulted in identical exports as the the first export after reinstall.

Comment: You are right, XCode exports some plist files (e.g. those containing NSUserDefaults) but unfortunately no documents at all.

Comment: For the time being, I downloaded Xcode 4.3.3 again. I'm now back up and running.

Comment: With the emulator it's no problem to get the data (it is stored on my mac's filesystem). But this is more like a workaround than a solution.

Comment: related Apple Dev Forums discussion (login required): https://devforums.apple.com/message/684941#684941

Answer (score 3):

This bug appears to be fixed in Xcode 4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I have been temporarily mounting Xcode 4.3.3 from a disk image and using Organizer there. Not the best solution, but seems like an "okay" workaround.

**UPDATE:** seems to be fixed in Xcode 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this problem also with Xcode 4.4, used iExplorer to get the files,  someone else said PhoneView should should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply for this question. I thought its worth putting up if anyone comes across this situation. The best way to get hold of the data is by directly accessing application folder by using an Application called "iPhone Explorer" or "iExplorer" both are free and will let you directly access iOS device file structure and you can copy Documents folder from it.

Hope it helps. Thank you :)