# Getting files off of iOS device for an app in testing

Tags: iphone

I save files to the Documents directory and wanted to look at the files themselves on the actual device.  I know how to do this in the simulator by going to the iPhone Simulator directory->App->Documents->files.  But is there a way to do this on the device?  I can't seem to figure it out.  In iTunes, I don't see my app since it's an app in testing.  And if I plug it into a Windows machine, I only see pictures and movies stored on the device, not anything specific to my app which makes sense.  Just didn't know if there was a way to get files off of the device.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Xcode's organiser window or by enabling iTunes File Sharing in your `Info.plist` file and going to the Apps tab on your device in iTunes.

Comment: I thought I was able to do this from the Organizer before but I couldn't find it today.  Thanks for the brain fart help.  Quick question though, why would it be Permission denied?  The device is a device I use for development.  Nevermind, I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666570/xcode-4-4-permission-denied-when-trying-to-download-application-data

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 6.1.1 (probably since 6, but 6.1.1 is what I have now), if you want files saved to the device's documents directory, you do...

- Select `Window` -> `Devices`
- Select your device
- In the `Installed Apps` section, select your app.
- Use the gear-icon to `Download Container` (that's the app's container)

  - Save it to your Desktop or someplace you can find it.
- The app container will open in Finder.

From there, you can look in the Documents directory, Library, tmp, etc., which are all in the higher-level folder, `AppData`.